# Best way to load dynamically generated JSX with React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some data returning from an API, and I'm trying to create a template to return a carousel with the images/headers/descriptions already formatted. When I return these, they always have `undefined` prefixed to them, and they are still strings. I tried using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` with `` String.raw`${x}` `` , which worked for something else, but this also doesn't render them as proper HTML. I'll paste my code below, any advice or guidance is appreciated.

```
export function CarouselImages({ projTitle, uid }) {
  const [json, setJson] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    get_slide_data(projTitle).then(setJson).catch(console.error);
  }, [projTitle]);
  console.log(json.TheMovieDBAPI);

  let Indicators = () => {
    let temp;
    for(let i in json.TheMovieDBAPI){
      if(i == 1){
        temp += `<button type="button" data-bs-target=${uid} data-bs-slide-to=${(i-1)} className="active" aria-label=${"Slide " + (i)} aria-current="true"></button>`
      }else{
        temp += `<button type="button" data-bs-target=${uid} data-bs-slide-to=${(i-1)} className="" aria-label=${"Slide " + (i)} aria-current="true"></button>`
      }
    }
    return temp;
  };

  let Slides = () => {
    let temp;
    for(let i in json[projTitle]){
      temp += `<div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src=${i.src} class="d-block">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                  <h5 class="h5">${i.heading}</h5>
                  <p>${i.desc}</p>
                </div>
              </div>`;
    }
    return temp;
  };

  console.log(Indicators);

  return (
    <div className="carousel slide projImg py-2" id={uid} data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div className="carousel-indicators">
        <Indicators />
      </div>
      <div className="carousel-inner">
        <Slides />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're getting undefined because you're trying to access an array of objects instead of an object. Perhaps you're confused for the difference in between JavaScript `of` and `in`. Generally speaking, `for(... of ...)` returns the iterated element, while `for(... in ...)` returns the index, so if you do:

```js
const arr = [{
  test: 1
}, {
  test: 2
}, {
  test: 3
}];
for (let i in arr) {
  console.log(i.test);
}
```

then it will output `undefined`, whilst

```js
const arr = [{
  test: 1
}, {
  test: 2
}, {
  test: 3
}];
for (let i of arr) {
  console.log(i.test);
}
```

gives the actual object.

In your case, you're getting undefined because you're treating a number as an object. You can instead do:

```js
for(let i of arr) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

or use the index:

```js
for(let i in arr) {
  console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

In your case it'd look something like:

```js
let Slides = () => {
  let temp;
  for (let i of json[projTitle]) {
    temp += `<div class="carousel-item active">
               <img src=${i.src} class="d-block">
               <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                 <h5 class="h5">${i.heading}</h5>
                 <p>${i.desc}</p>
               </div>
             </div>`;
  }
  return temp;
};
```

#### Update

Because you're operating on objects, if you try `for(... of ...)` you'll get an "object not iterable" error (because it's not an iterable). To iterate through objects, you would need to use a `for(... in ...)` loop and access it like an array, e.g.:

```js
for(let i in myObj) {
  // `i` is the object key
  console.log(myObj[i]); // object contents being iterated
}
```

The exact same applies for your case.

Comment: This definitely cleared some questions I had up, but unfortunately isn't exactly the answer needed. The react fails to compile when I use of, and it says the object is not iterable. I did have questions about in vs of though, and those are cleared up now, so thanks!

Comment: @morthemex oh, based on your code I assumed it's an array. I've adjusted my answer.